# hide and show a dynamic created UL list with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, show-hide

Well, as the question says, Im found a code that makes the UL list show and hide with Jquery.

Here is a link on jsFiddle and when I made a UL list directly on the HTML it works but not if I add it dynamically with javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/p2v0ka1s/4/

The problem I found is that the Jquery creates classnames that is called and changed by clicking, and those classnames doesnt apply to my dynamic UL list and I dont know why. Can you please help me?

Here is my code that creates it dynamically and the test of jquery that doesnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/aytnt4bL/1/ The Jquery code is at the button of the javascript code (I added it there, but I have it as a separate sourcefile in my computer.

I add the code here in the text too, so you can see it!
It works perfect with non-dynamic UL list so there is my issue, to make it work with my dynamic created UL list. Thanks!

```
 $(function() {
    $('.contactlist').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var sub = $('> ul', this);
      if(sub.length) {
        if(sub.is(':visible')) {
          sub.hide();
          sub.removeClass('open');
        } else {
          $('.contactlist .open').hide().removeClass('open');
          sub.show();
          sub.parents('ul:not(.contactlist)').addClass('open').show();
          sub.addClass('open');
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
$('body').on('click','.contactlist',function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var sub = $('> ul', this);
  if(sub.length) {
    if(sub.is(':visible')) {
      sub.hide();
      sub.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      $('.contactlist .open').hide().removeClass('open');
      sub.show();
      sub.parents('ul:not(.contactlist)').addClass('open').show();
      sub.addClass('open');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, i did read the link and tried that and doesnt work either. What i did see now is that the jquery load BEFORE the dynamically created UL list. Can that have something to do with why it isnt working? How can I do so the dynamic loads before the jquery? or doesnt that make any difference? Thanks for you help!